Extracting Only the External Edges of Complex BufferGeometry in Three.js
I'm currently working on a project involving zone creation and collision detection using Three.js, where my application correctly handles collisions and generates a BufferGeometry as the outcome. My goal is to visually represent a frame around these zones to clearly delineate their boundaries.
With bounding box, Simple shape
While I can easily create a bounding box for simple geometries (which works well as shown in the attached image), I encounter issues with more complex geometries. The bounding box does not accurately reflect the actual complex shape of the zones.
BufferGometry, Complex shapes
To address this, I attempted to highlight the edges of the geometry by creating LineSegments from the vertices. This approach works to some extent, but it results in too many internal lines being displayed. I need a way to filter out these internal lines so that only the external edges—the actual outline of the complex shapes—are visible.
Here is the relevant part of my code where I attempt to extract and display these edges:
const calculateZoneCollision = (zone: PotreeVolume) => {
    const viewer: PotreeViewer = (window as any).viewer;

    if (!zone) return;

    zone.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    const allVolumes = viewer.scene.volumes.filter((volume) => volume.uuid !== zone.uuid);
    const volumeMeshes = allVolumes.map((v) => {
        return createMeshFromVolume(v);
    });

    let zoneMesh = createMeshFromVolume(zone);
    let zoneOBB = createOBBFromMesh(zoneMesh, viewer);

    let resultMesh;

    volumeMeshes.forEach((volume) => {
        volume.updateMatrixWorld(true);

        let volumeOBB = createOBBFromMesh(volume, viewer);

        if (zoneOBB.intersectsOBB(volumeOBB)) {
            console.log(`Collision detected with volume: ${volume.name}`);

            let originalCSGZone;

            if (!resultMesh) {
                originalCSGZone = CSG.fromMesh(zoneMesh);
            } else {
                originalCSGZone = CSG.fromMesh(resultMesh);
            }

            let csgZone = originalCSGZone.clone();

            let csgVolume = CSG.fromMesh(volume);
            csgZone = csgZone.subtract(csgVolume);

            const collisionInfo = calculateCollisionInfo(zoneOBB, volumeOBB);

            const details = getCollisionDetails(zoneOBB, volumeOBB, collisionInfo);
            if (details) {
                console.log(`Point of collide: `, details.collisionPoint);
                console.log(`Side of impact: `, details.side);
                console.log('Volume: ', zone, zoneMesh, zoneOBB);
            }

            const resultGeometry = CSG.toGeometry(csgZone, zoneMesh.matrix);
            const resultMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, transparent: true,      opacity: 0.001 });
            resultMesh = new Mesh(resultGeometry, resultMaterial);
            resultMesh.applyMatrix4(zoneMesh.matrixWorld);

            const vertices = [];
            const positionAttribute = resultGeometry.getAttribute('position');

            for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i++) {
                const vertex = new Vector3();
                vertex.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, i);
                vertices.push([vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z]);
            }

            const matrixElements = resultMesh.matrix.elements;
        } else {
            console.log(`Collision not detected`);
        }
    });

    if (resultMesh) {
        const outerEdges = extractOuterEdges(resultMesh.geometry);

        outerEdges.applyMatrix4(zoneMesh.matrixWorld);
        viewer.scene.scene.add(outerEdges);
        viewer.scene.scene.add(resultMesh);

        setTimeout(() => {
            viewer.scene.scene.remove(resultMesh);
            viewer.scene.scene.remove(outerEdges);
        }, 160);
    }
};

function extractOuterEdges(geometry) {
    const indexAttribute = geometry.index;
    const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute('position');
    const normalsAttribute = geometry.getAttribute('normal');
    const edgeMap = new Map();
    const edgeFaces = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i < indexAttribute.count; i += 3) {
        let indices = [indexAttribute.getX(i), indexAttribute.getX(i + 1), indexAttribute.getX(i + 2)];
        let triangleNormals = [
            new Vector3(normalsAttribute.getX(i), normalsAttribute.getY(i), normalsAttribute.getZ(i)),
            new Vector3(normalsAttribute.getX(i + 1), normalsAttribute.getY(i + 1), normalsAttribute.getZ(i + 1)),
            new Vector3(normalsAttribute.getX(i + 2), normalsAttribute.getY(i + 2), normalsAttribute.getZ(i + 2)),
        ];

        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            let edgeKey = [indices[j], indices[(j + 1) % 3]].sort().join('_');
            if (!edgeMap.has(edgeKey)) {
                edgeMap.set(edgeKey, 1);
                edgeFaces.set(edgeKey, [triangleNormals[j]]);
            } else {
                edgeMap.set(edgeKey, edgeMap.get(edgeKey) + 1);
                edgeFaces.get(edgeKey).push(triangleNormals[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    const outerEdgesGeometry = new BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [];

    edgeMap.forEach((count, key) => {
        if (count === 1 || (count === 2 && !areNormalsCoPlanar(edgeFaces.get(key)[0], edgeFaces.get(key)[1]))) {
            let vertexIndices = key.split('_').map(Number);
            vertices.push(
                new Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, vertexIndices[0]),
                new Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, vertexIndices[1])
            );
        }
    });

    outerEdgesGeometry.setFromPoints(vertices);
    const lineMaterial = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
    const lineSegments = new LineSegments(outerEdgesGeometry, lineMaterial);

    return lineSegments;
}

function areNormalsCoPlanar(normal1, normal2) {
    return normal1.dot(normal2) > 0.995; // Stricter coplanarity check
}


Hmm, from description, i don't think you are going to make it acceptable in terms of performance.  I think your best bet is to looks if CSG provides bounding box of resulting volume, or calculate bounding box yourself. Normally outline done via providing mask color, or stencil, and then edge detection on that in post processing... Processing vertices like that going to be slow as hell...

const calculateZoneCollision = (zone: PotreeVolume) => {
    const viewer: PotreeViewer = (window as any).viewer;

    if (!zone) return;

    zone.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    const allVolumes = viewer.scene.volumes.filter((volume) => volume.uuid !== zone.uuid);
    const volumeMeshes = allVolumes.map((v) => {
        return createMeshFromVolume(v);
    });

    let zoneMesh = createMeshFromVolume(zone);
    let zoneOBB = createOBBFromMesh(zoneMesh, viewer);

    let resultMesh;

    volumeMeshes.forEach((volume) => {
        volume.updateMatrixWorld(true);

        let volumeOBB = createOBBFromMesh(volume, viewer);

        if (zoneOBB.intersectsOBB(volumeOBB)) {
            console.log(`Collision detected with volume: ${volume.name}`);

            let originalCSGZone;

            if (!resultMesh) {
                originalCSGZone = CSG.fromMesh(zoneMesh);
            } else {
                originalCSGZone = CSG.fromMesh(resultMesh);
            }

            let csgZone = originalCSGZone.clone();

            let csgVolume = CSG.fromMesh(volume);
            csgZone = csgZone.subtract(csgVolume);

            const collisionInfo = calculateCollisionInfo(zoneOBB, volumeOBB);

            const details = getCollisionDetails(zoneOBB, volumeOBB, collisionInfo);
            if (details) {
                console.log(`Point of collide: `, details.collisionPoint);
                console.log(`Side of impact: `, details.side);
                console.log('Volume: ', zone, zoneMesh, zoneOBB);
            }

            const resultGeometry = CSG.toGeometry(csgZone, zoneMesh.matrix);
            const resultMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.001 });
            resultMesh = new Mesh(resultGeometry, resultMaterial);
            resultMesh.applyMatrix4(zoneMesh.matrixWorld);

            const vertices = [];
            const positionAttribute = resultGeometry.getAttribute('position');

            for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i++) {
                const vertex = new Vector3();
                vertex.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, i);
                vertices.push([vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z]);
            }

            const matrixElements = resultMesh.matrix.elements;
        } else {
            console.log(`Collision not detected`);
        }
    });

    if (resultMesh) {
        let volume = CSG.fromMesh(resultMesh);
        const frame = filterOuterEdges(volume);

        viewer.scene.scene.add(frame);
        viewer.scene.scene.add(resultMesh);

        setTimeout(() => {
            viewer.scene.scene.remove(resultMesh);
            // viewer.scene.scene.remove(frame);
        }, 160);
    }
};

export default calculateZoneCollision;

function filterOuterEdges(csg) {
    const edges = new Map();

    // Goes trough all poygons and all edges
    csg.polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
        const vertices = polygon.vertices;
        for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            const start = vertices[i].pos;
            const end = vertices[(i + 1) % vertices.length].pos;
            const edgeKey = vertexKey(start, end);

            if (edges.has(edgeKey)) {
                // If bouth polygons have same or look a like normal that might be inner edge
                const edge = edges.get(edgeKey);
                if (edge.normal.dot(polygon.plane.normal) > 0.95) {
                    edges.delete(edgeKey); // Delete becouse that will be inner edge
                }
            } else {
                // Save edge with his normal for later check
                edges.set(edgeKey, { start: start, end: end, normal: polygon.plane.normal });
            }
        }
    });

    // Now we make geometry with outside edges
    const outerEdgesGeometry = new BufferGeometry();
    const positions = new Float32Array(edges.size * 2 * 3);
    let positionIndex = 0;

    edges.forEach((edge) => {
        positions.set([edge.start.x, edge.start.y, edge.start.z], positionIndex);
        positionIndex += 3;
        positions.set([edge.end.x, edge.end.y, edge.end.z], positionIndex);
        positionIndex += 3;
    });

    outerEdgesGeometry.setAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

    const lineMaterial = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
    const lineSegments = new LineSegments(outerEdgesGeometry, lineMaterial);
    return lineSegments;
}

function vertexKey(vertex1, vertex2) {
    const minVertex =
        vertex1.x < vertex2.x
            ? vertex1
            : vertex1.x === vertex2.x && vertex1.y < vertex2.y
            ? vertex1
            : vertex1.x === vertex2.x && vertex1.y === vertex2.y && vertex1.z < vertex2.z
            ? vertex1
            : vertex2;
    const maxVertex = vertex1 === minVertex ? vertex2 : vertex1;
    return `${minVertex.x}_${minVertex.y}_${minVertex.z}-${maxVertex.x}_${maxVertex.y}_${maxVertex.z}`;
} 

So far, the best solution to the problem, but still not perfect enough. Now I use the vertices from CSG and filter them. Everything works quickly enough, but there are still some internal points that I still have to filter out.
Side view, Top view (The red frame is BufferGeometry that I want to filter)
